# Multi coin paper wallet generator?

Tags: paper-wallet, coldstorage

Is there a site where I can generate paper wallets for multiple cryptocurrency addresses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find a good one. So I made one:

Demo: https://xcubicle.github.io/memorypaperwallet/

Source: https://github.com/xcubicle/memorypaperwallet

Most paper wallet generators just generate bitcoin and derived coins. There wasn't one that generated non-btc ones like ethereum and monero. And the artwork is user changable too! Feedback welcomed.

[image]

enter image description here
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am still researching this topic, but appears that https://walletgenerator.net/ is a good place to start.

Note that best practices demand that you download the html+javascript application of a paper-wallet generator, and execute it locally on your computer: So for that process you should go here:

https://github.com/MichaelMure/WalletGenerator.net

Then you should use a "dumb printer", preferably only connected via USB and one that does not have any kind of memory.

If you are investigating paper wallets, I also recommend that you read about the Glacier Protocol https://glacierprotocol.org/ which is definately Bitcoin-focused but does seem to cover very clearly the pitfalls and work-arounds associated with long-term storage and process protection required for archival quality paper-wallets.

Comment: Doing it offline is just fine. All the rest is just paranoia thinking someone is always watching every step of the way.